# click function simultaneously and return in text while

Tags: angularjs

It is such that I must have been an error if you just have empty content in input the boxes. It must first tell it when you click on my button.

when the specific error should I add an error class as boostrap has when an error occurs. How would I do this?

```
var app = angular.module('UserValue', [])
app.controller('UserFirstValue', function ($scope) {
    var mail = $scope.emai;
    var password = $scope.password;
    var firstname = $scope.Firstname;
    var lastname = $scope.Lastname;
    var age = $scope.age;

    $scope.CheckUserValue = function () {
        if (mail == null && password == null && firstname == null && lastname == null && age == null) {
            //show error her
            return "Remember to throw content in!"
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

create.cshtml:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" ng-app="UserValue" ng-controller="UserFirstValue">
   //Show error her
   <div class="OutError" ng-show="CheckUserValue()" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="CheckUserValue()" id="clickUserCreate"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Error are: 
It shows no means subtitled forward.

Comment: Im pretty confused as to what exactly you are asking here... Could you be more specific and maybe double check your grammar above

Comment: Oh, I am unfortunately dyslexic. What I ask for is how is it that I can display my error message appears on the page? @MaxwellLasky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so you had multiple issues here... Im just going to leave a JS bin here for you to look over and it should totally resolve the issues you were having previously trying to set up your validation.

https://jsbin.com/nanizafizi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6" ng-app="UserValue" ng-controller="UserFirstValue" ng-hide="hideForm">
   {{errorMessage}}
     <form ng-submit="submitForm()" role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>First Name:</label>
         <input type="text" ng-model="user.first" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Last Name:</label>
         <input type="text" ng-model="user.last" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Email address:</label>
         <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Password:</label>
         <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Age:</label>
         <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="user.age">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('UserValue', [])
app.controller('UserFirstValue', function ($scope) {

   $scope.errorMessage = "";
   $scope.hideForm = false;

   $scope.submitForm = function() {
      if ($scope.user === undefined ||
        $scope.user.first === undefined ||
        $scope.user.last === undefined ||
        $scope.user.email === undefined ||
        $scope.user.password === undefined ||
        $scope.user.age === undefined) {
        $scope.errorMessage = "Oops it looks like you missed a field!";
      }

     else {
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.hideForm = true;
     } 
  }

});
```

Comment: You will see that the $scope.user object contains all the properties of the submission info on the form so no need to redefine these variables as you were doing in your controller

Comment: Thanks for help i hope u giv me +1 ! Good day to u